# How do i utilize # to develop a one page application like gmail?

Tags: javascript

i want to develop a one page application where it should utilize AJAX to a full extent like the one used in Gmail and Facebook. i am aware of the light JS Framework called Sammy.js which does the work. the only thing why i don't want to use this is it is built on top of jQuery. i know jQuery is awesome and nice and i should start using it right away. but FYI i tend to learn things from scratch and later on i would want to adopt for Frameworks.

here is the link to what exactly i want to do..

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/demo/index.html#/compose

is there any alternative so that i can achieve the same using plain Javascript?

thank you...

Comment: +1 for "how do I utilize #" c.f. XmlHttpRequest. I lol'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you'll be using jQuery, have a look at this plugin:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Edit: Oops, misread your question. I thought you do want jQuery.. but you don't.
Well.. still use it (or another javascript library if you don't like jQuery). First of all, you'll most likely not be aware of all browser-specific issues. Then your code will be much less readable if you use classic plain JavaScript for everything. If someone else will be working with your code he'll also have a hard time to get into it unless you document it really well.

So as you see, there's no good reason not to use jQuery in your app. If you want it for learning purposes ok - but then don't do that in a real application but with some small testcases.

Comment: i never thought of cross browser issues. only thing i cared about is learning JS. well i will surely use jQuery for real time application. :)

Comment: I think you learn better JS if you use jQuery and work with anonymous functions/closures, callbacks, etc. than when doing raw JS. Chances are high that you find old/bad stuff when searching for raw js stuff (e.g. setTimeout with a string argument or `onclick` attributes)

Answer (score 1):

using plain JavaScript to accomplish what you're looking to do is nice and educational and all, but using jQuery to accomplish it is soooo much quicker and effective. You could do XmlHttpRequests with callbacks etc., or you could $.ajax.

My advice, start learning jQuery now and start simple with a basic ajax request. You'll pick it up very quickly!

Comment: lol, i appreciate the advice. almost 90% of Javascript coders want me to go with jQuery no matter how many times i refuse, i tried explaining i want to do this because i want to learn both JS and jQuery this way i could have solid understanding of the core rather then just the frameworks API . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without JQuery, what you'll learn though is the million and one differences between each browser's javascript engine, and you'll have to account for all of them. Personally I think there's better things you could be learning, but up to you. If you want to, check out [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID) and go from there.